# Could I put both the AMD64 and i386 Ubuntu images on one usb drive?

Tags: uefi, 64-bit, 32-bit, bios, disk-image

Basically, the PC I use at home is 64-bit and the computers at my school are 32-bit. I'm kind of doubting it, but I'm wondering if I can make a persistent liveUSB of Ubuntu with the startup disk maker or something that can boot on either 32-bit or 64-bit systems. (I'm doing a project for a computer maintenance and repair class).

I should add that the reason I don't want to use only 32-bit is I have a UEFI system at home and I don't really want to have to mess around with that every time I try to boot from USB at home.